# Bad Performance with ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, performance, expandoobject

im having a terrible problem with a List of ExpandoObject reading their data with a Incoming Products, I cant use a normal class cause im using a list of products, and some products use size as number(20,21,22...), other as letter(S, M, L, XL....) i put this on a Grid, in each size column i put a quantity that each store receives from supplier

this is my list:

```
listaGrade = new List<dynamic>();

foreach(product p in BD.Proc)
{
    foreach(store s in BD.Stores)
    {
        dynamic itemGradeDinamic = new ExpandoObject();

        itemGradeDinamic.MODELDES = p.MODELDES;
        itemGradeDinamic.TIPO = p.TIPO;
        itemGradeDinamic.DESCRIPTION = p.DESCRIPTION;
        itemGradeDinamic.STORE = s.CODE;
        itemGradeDinamic.STOREDES = s.NAME;
        itemGradeDinamic.SUBTOTAL = 0;

        foreach (string size in p.sizes)
        {
            ((IDictionary<String, Object>)itemGradeDinamic).Add(size, 0);
        }
        listaGrade.add(itemGradeDinamic);
    }
}
```

Getting data:

```
object description, modelDes = "";
object qtde, store = 0;
foreach (ExpandoObject obj in listaGrade)
{
   foreach (string size in "products".sizes)
   {
        if (((IDictionary<string, object>)obj).TryGetValue(size, out qtde))
        {
            if (Convert.ToDecimal(qtde) > 0)
            {
                 ((IDictionary<string, object>)obj).TryGetValue("DESCRIPTION", out description);
                 ((IDictionary<string, object>)obj).TryGetValue("MODELDES", out modelDes);
                 ((IDictionary<string, object>)obj).TryGetValue("TIPO", out tipo);
                            ((IDictionary<string, object>)obj).TryGetValue("SHOP", out store);

             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: The trick here is to not use ExpandoObject. It is not meant as a general purpose type you can use for everything. It's meant for those parts of the code where a dynamic object is the only option. Why can't you simply store the size as a string? That would easily handle size 20, 21, etc.

Comment: "I cant use a normal class cause im using a list of products, and some products use size as number(20,21,22...), other as letter(S, M, L, XL....)" -- why not use `object` or `string` to handle both cases?  Using `ExpandoObject` is going to cost you in terms of performance.

Comment: Bad choice leads to bad performance. As others wrote before, sanitize your object hierarchy.

Comment: I'm using the ExpandoObject on WPF grid ItemsSource [GRID IMAGE](http://imageshack.com/a/img836/3528/1m3s.png), sometimes this list of expando object can be higher than 50 objects easily... i'm new on C# and im having problems to define the better way

Answer (score 0):

The `ExpandoObject` class does not replace static types.

In this particular case, you have to discard the `ExpandoObject` in favour of the custom static class. If you need something that contains a dynamic data structure, use `Dictionary<string,string>` or `Dictionary<string,object>` depending on the   task.

Comment: Static class is somewhat else than a statically typed object.

Comment: I'm new on C# and dont know many commands and how to discern the better code to use and how to do many times, this is the [GRID](http://imageshack.com/a/img836/3528/1m3s.png) that i use in WPF.
Can u explain me the better way to do this?